# Filter by price percentage reduction - ASC and DESC

Tags: magento

I try to add a filter with percentage reduction on price

I managed to do it with the following code :

```
->order('(price_index.final_price / price_index.price)', 'DESC')
```

but when I try to set the direction to ASC, it display the products with the same order as DESC ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the code where you're trying to change the ordering? Are you sure you have a valid value in both fields?

Comment: To change the ordering, I just do  `->order('(price_index.final_price / price_index.price)', 'ASC')`  
When I don't order, the products are ordered by price and when I do it works great for DESC but not for ASC